# Adding name of the sheets of one workbook to combo box of another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 workbooks **test1** (has 3 sheets) and **tests**(has 1 sheet).

In **tests** I have a combo box named **ComboBox1**.I have to add the name of the sheets from workbook **test1** in this **ComboBox1**.

I have written the following code

```
Sub Workbook_open()

Dim sht As Worksheet

Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("test1.xls")

For Each sht In wkbSource.Worksheets

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ComboBox1.AddItem sht.Name

Next sht

End Sub
```

It is giving me an error

ERROR : Object doesn't support this property or method on line 
 **ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ComboBox1.AddItem sht.Name**

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that error because of your use of `ActiveWorkbook`. After you open `"test1.xls"`, it becomes active and hence the line `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ComboBox1.AddItem sht.Name` fails as it cannot find the combobox.

Replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook`

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ComboBox1.AddItem sht.Name
```

Comment: Yes perfect.Thanks :)
What if I don't want to open the workbook and just want to set the path ?

Comment: To get the sheet names you will have to open it. Else use ADODB to get sheet names from a closed workbook